Using NODE_OPTIONS in google node distroless image
I am trying to build a node js image by using a google distroless image. I am unable to parse the arguments in the node command within the CMD of the dockerfile even though the environment is variable in the container.
I tried printing the variables and I can see that the NODE_OPTION is not populated.
docker run -it --entrypoint=sh --env HEAP_SIZE=4096 hello-world-app:latest
/usr/src/app # env
HOSTNAME=8877ad81ddc7
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=
SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
HEAP_SIZE=4096
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/busybox
PWD=/usr/src/app
/usr/src/app # ^C

Dockerfile
# Dockerfile
FROM node:18.18.2-bookworm-slim AS build

WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json files
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

# Install dependencies
RUN npm ci

# Copy application files
COPY . .

# Expose port 3000
#EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run the application
#CMD ["npm", "start"]

# Build and cleanup
ENV NODE_ENV=production
#RUN npm run build

FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs18-debian12:debug

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=build /app .

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=$HEAP_SIZE

# Start server
CMD ["--unhandled-rejections=warn",  "--experimental-specifier-resolution=node", "index.js"]

I am using below function to print the statistics.
console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics());

But it seems that it is not able to parse in the CMD.
Output:
docker run -it --env HEAP_SIZE=10000 hello-world-app:latest
(node:1) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution flag is experimental. It could change or be removed at any time.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server is running on http://localhost:3000
{
  total_heap_size: 11845632,
  total_heap_size_executable: 786432,
  total_physical_size: 12292096,
  total_available_size: 2188348504,
  used_heap_size: 9213392,
  heap_size_limit: 2197815296,
  malloced_memory: 690880,
  peak_malloced_memory: 1042744,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 1,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0,
  total_global_handles_size: 8192,
  used_global_handles_size: 3872,
  external_memory: 1299869
}

I am expecting HEAP_SIZE to be the environment variable available in the container while initiating the node process.
UPDATE: I tried passing the while NODE_OPTIONS as an env variable at runtime and it works. It completely replaced the previous value defined in the Dockerfile.
